# Implementing Stacks and Queues using a Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list, stack, queue

I'm trying to go over some previous homework problems in my computer science class with regards to Linked List. This question is really bothering me on how I should go about this, where it wants me to implement a "Stack" and a "Queue" class to go along using my Linked List class I made a while back. That is all the question states, so would I have to use my ListNode class which is this.

```
class ListNode(object):

    def __init__(self, item = None, link = None):

        '''creates a ListNode with the specified data value and link
        post: creates a ListNode with the specified data value and link'''

        self.item = item
        self.link = link
```

How would I go about making a stack class that can push and pop? Would my code look like this or will I be way off?

```
from ListNode import ListNode

class LinkedStack(object):
    def __init__(self, ListNode.item):
        stack = []
    def push(self,item):
        self.append(ListNode.item)
        self.size += 1
    def isEmpty(self):
        return not self
```

I just based that code off examples I have seen on this web page. Any help to make a simple stack class based off a linked list? For some reason it wants me to test my code using this class that was given to me which was this.

```
def isPalindrome(phrase):
    forward = Queue()
    reverse = Stack()
    extractLetters(phrase, forward, reverse)
    return sameSequence(forward, reverse)

#------------------------------------------------------------

def extractLetters(phrase, q, s):
    for ch in phrase:
        if ch.isalpha():
            ch = ch.lower()
            q.enqueue(ch)
            s.push(ch)

#------------------------------------------------------------

def sameSequence(q, s):
    while q.size() > 0:
        ch1 = q.dequeue()
        ch2 = s.pop()
        if ch1 != ch2:
            return False
    return True
```

Thanks to whoever helps me in advance!

Comment: Stacks add to the end, remove from the end. Queues add to the end, remove from the head. Beyond that there's not much to think about.

Comment: Could you write an example of code I could do for my stack and queue class? I'm sorry I was always confused about this area that is why I'm revisiting it

Comment: Are you really saying that you don't understand the concept of inserting and removing from the head or tail of a linked list?

Comment: @MarkRansom Sorry I'm fairly new to coding, you don't have to be a prick about it. I'm just trying to understand this.

Comment: And I'm trying to understand what it is that you don't understand. It appears you might have trouble with the concept of a linked list altogether, but at this point I can't tell. Once you have a working linked list, building on it to get a stack or queue is *trivial*.

Comment: Your listnode class is pointless if you're going to use the inbuilt list type anyway.  You should try to implement a linked list class without using the inbuilt list. Then create your stack and queue classes in terms of that.   For some examples implementations of these you can see rosetta code.

Answer (score 1):

one way to create stack using python list is using list's append & pop functions.

Example stack class:

```
class stack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def pop(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            print "Nothing to remove from stack"
            return None
        return self.data.pop()

    def push(self, item):
        self.data.append(item)

    def isEmpty(self):
        if len(self.data) == 0:
            return True
        return False


s = stack()
s.push(1)
s.push(2)
s.push(3)
print s.pop()
print s.pop()
print s.pop()
print s.pop()
```

Output:

```
3
2
1
Nothing to remove from stack
None
```

Comment: I see that would work, but I need to add my list nodes in that because it still needs to use my linked list.